# Longest Column in multi-column Excel Range (in a single formula)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a range where different columns may have different numbers of values (but there won't be gaps in the sequence within a column) I'd like to know the length of the longest column. To be more demanding, I'd like it in a single formula.

So given a range like this:

```
      |  A   B   C   D
   ---+---+---+---+---
    1 |  1   2   3   4
    2 |  2   9   5   6
    3 |      5   5
    4 |          4
    5 |
```

.. the answer I want is 4.

Something that works in this case is

```
=MAX(COUNT(A1:A999),COUNT(B1:B999),COUNT(C1:C999),Count(D1:D999))
```

But it's (a) ugly and (b) inflexible - doesn't cater for the case where a column might be added.

I tried something like this, hoping for an array giving the set of column counts (hoping to wrap a `MAX()` around it):

```
{=COUNT(OFFSET(A1,0,COLUMN(A1:D1)-COLUMN(A1),999,1))}
```

.. but it only gives a single cell, which always seems to be the count on the first column.

I know this could be easily solved in VBA but for several reasons (not least curiosity) I'd like to see if it can be solved in a single (probably array) formula.

Comment: I claim no credit for this one: `=MAX(ROW(1:100)*(A1:D100<>""))` From [Bob Umlas](http://www.emailoffice.com/excel/arrays-bobumlas.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try this with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER:

```
=MAX(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A:D,,COLUMN(A:D)-MIN(COLUMN(A:D)),,1)))
```

Any rectangular range can be used in place of `A:D`.

Comment: On a sidenote, would you happen to know why this array formula seems to work with `SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET...` but not `COUNTA(OFFSET...` (or `COUNT`)?

Comment: The `OFFSET(...)` part of the formula returns an array consisting of range references when array-entered. `SUBTOTAL` acts on each reference in the array and returns an array of values but `COUNTA` and other summary functions only ever return a single value when an array is supplied as an argument

Comment: I don't think I've ever found a need for `SUBTOTAL` before. Time to do some learning. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeWoodhouse: Generally it seems to be functions that natively take range reference arguments that allow this sort of "range array" construct. So for example `COUNTIF(OFFSET(...),"<>")` works but `SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(...)<>"")` doesn't.